# Access odd-named object returned by getSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm downloading data from Yahoo using `quantmod`:

```
> getSymbols("HNZ-A.TO")
[1] "HNZ-A.TO"
Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  downloaded length 70893 != reported length 200
```

The file shows up in my R workspace. The data is there and I can use `edit` to see the object, but I can't use the object.  For example:

```
> head(HNZ-A.TO)
Error in head(HNZ - A.TO) : object 'HNZ' not found
```

What can I do to use this object?

Answer (score 3):

Use back-ticks or `get`.

```
HNZA.TO <- `HNZ-A.TO`
HNZA.TO <- get("HNZ-A.TO")
```

Or you could avoid this all-together by setting `auto.assign=FALSE` in your call to `getSymbols`.

```
HNZA.TO <- getSymbols("HNZ-A.TO", auto.assign=FALSE)
```

You might also want to adjust the column names, via:

```
colnames(HNZA.TO) <- make.names(colnames(HNZA.TO))
```

Answer (score 3):

`HNZ <- getSymbols('HNZ-A.TO', auto.assign=FALSE)` per the help page for getSymbols.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to `setSymbolLookup` to tell `getSymbols` to use a different Symbol in the query.

```
> setSymbolLookup(HNZ=list(src="yahoo", name="HNZ-A.TO"))
> getSymbols("HNZ")
[1] "HNZ"
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, but so you cannot get the quotes. Maybe another solution could be:

HNZ<-read.csv("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=HNZ-A.TO&ignore=.csv", stringsAsFactors=F)

head(HNZ)

The advantage is that it is still easy to get the columns you want easily.